# How can I create the CSS layout for a table will work with mobile, tablets and desktop

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table which has 3 rows and 4 columns.
I want to make the images resize to fit the screen size for mobile, tablet and deskop.
So I want all 12 images to display on the screen at once.
What CSS would I need to do this?

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><img src=""></td>
<td><img src=""></td>
<td><img src=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src=""></td>
<td><img src=""></td>
<td><img src=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src=""></td>
<td><img src=""></td>
<td><img src=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src=""></td>
<td><img src=""></td>
<td><img src=""></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You need something like "flexbox" or "css-grid". Here are two fun resources to learn more: https://flexboxfroggy.com/ https://cssgridgarden.com/

Comment: Thanks thats great learning the CSS Grid, for some reason in the browser it displays correctly but in the android mobile app that iframes the same code the grid is just 1 column with all 12 images in 12 rows

Comment: Does it correctly scale on desktop, if you narrow the viewport? Have you used  <meta name="viewport"content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> at the start of your document?

Comment: .frame {
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0 none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

Comment: Thats the iframe css code

Comment: But have you included the code I mentioned at the top of your html code?

Comment: I have <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"> at the top

Comment: changed the code to include <meta name="viewport"content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> still get the same effect in the iframe

Answer (score 0):

Try this code or you can use `row` and `col` for that.
But i have used `media query` of css in that you can adjust your size and make it responsive

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 776px) {
            img {
               height: 150px;
               width: 150px;
        }
    }
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="https://demo.phpgang.com/crop-images/demo_files/pool.jpg"></td>
        <td><img src="https://demo.phpgang.com/crop-images/demo_files/pool.jpg"></td>
        <td><img src="https://demo.phpgang.com/crop-images/demo_files/pool.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="https://demo.phpgang.com/crop-images/demo_files/pool.jpg"></td>
        <td><img src="https://demo.phpgang.com/crop-images/demo_files/pool.jpg"></td>
        <td><img src="https://demo.phpgang.com/crop-images/demo_files/pool.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="https://demo.phpgang.com/crop-images/demo_files/pool.jpg"></td>
        <td><img src="https://demo.phpgang.com/crop-images/demo_files/pool.jpg"></td>
        <td><img src="https://demo.phpgang.com/crop-images/demo_files/pool.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="https://demo.phpgang.com/crop-images/demo_files/pool.jpg"></td>
        <td><img src="https://demo.phpgang.com/crop-images/demo_files/pool.jpg"></td>
        <td><img src="https://demo.phpgang.com/crop-images/demo_files/pool.jpg"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You can adjust the size of image you want in media tag